# get line number of a MethodDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to create a parser of Java files, but I can't get the **correct** line number of each method. this is the code that I've right now:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setSource(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Main.java"), "UTF-8").toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);

Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null /* IProgressMonitor */);

cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        System.out.println("MethodName: " + node.getName().toString());
        System.out.println("MethodLineNumber: " + cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()));

        return false;
    }
});
```

imagine that we're parsing the following class

```
public class Main
{
  /**
   *
   */
  public Main() {

  }
}
```

the code

```
cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition())
```

instead of returning 6, returns 3. apparently the eclipse.jdt API considers that javacode also belongs to the method. so, my question is, how to get the **correct** line number of method Main()?

**EDIT_1**

we can have access to the JavaDoc:

```
String javadoc = node.getJavadoc().toString();
```

and count the number of lines

```
Pattern NLINE = Pattern.compile("(\n)|(\r)|(\r\n)");
Matcher m = NLINE.matcher(javadoc);
int lines = 1;
while (m.find())
  lines++;
```

and in fact works for that case but not to all cases, like for example

```
public class Main
{
  /**
   * 
   *
   *
   *
   *
   *
   *
   */
  public Main() {

  }
}
```

-

```
node.getJavadoc().toString():
/** 
 */
```

---

```
public class Main
{
  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param <K> the key type
   * @param <V> the value type
   */
  public Main() {

  }
}
```

-

```
node.getJavadoc().toString():
/** 
 * Constructor
 * @param<K>
 *  the key type
 * @param<V>
 *  the value type
 */
```

apparently, toString method of Javadoc class ignores empty lines and considers label @param as two lines, etc.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `getName()` of `MethodDeclaration` to get the `ASTNode` for the method name and get the line number of the name.

Answer (score 2):

A sample code, hope it helps.

```
    public MethodNode getMethodforGivenLineNum(String srcFilePath, int linenum) {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);

        char[] fileContent = null;
        try {
            fileContent = getFileContent(srcFilePath).toCharArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("getMethodforGivenLineNum-getFileContent failed!\n%s", srcFilePath);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        parser.setSource(fileContent);

        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

        List<MethodNode> methodNodeList = new ArrayList<>();

        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
                SimpleName methodName = node.getName();

                int startLineNum = cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition());

                int endLineNum = cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition() + node.getLength());

                methodNodeList.add(new MethodNode(methodName.toString(), node, startLineNum, endLineNum));
                return false;
            }
        });
```